# All Integer solutions to $2006=(x+y)^{2}+3x+y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I find all the solutions to

> $2006=(x+y)^{2}+3x+y$

Where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

One such solution I found was $(x,y)=(1000,-998)$. I did it by the following,

$2006+3y=(x+y)^{2}+3(x+y)+y$

$2(1003+y)=(x+y)(x+y+3)$.

Which upon solving the system, we will get $x=1000$ and $y=-998$.

How can I continue to find other solutions? 'Cause I noticed that $(13,31)$ also works but I'm not sure where that's derived from, and I have a feeling that there's more.

Comment: If my calculations are correct, the equation is equivalent to $(2x+2y+1)^2 + 8x = 8025$; so for any integer $n$, you should be able to solve $x+y = n$ and $x = \frac{8025 - (2n+1)^2}{8} = 1003 - \frac{n + n^2}{2}$, so $y = -1003 + \frac{3n+n^2}{2}$, to get a solution.

Comment: OK, in retrospect, that's maybe a bit overcomplicated; you should be able to solve $x+y = n$ and $3x+y = 2006-n^2$ for any integer $n$ to get a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are in fact infinitely many solutions.

We re-write the equation as a quadratic in $y$:
$$y^2 + (2x+1)y + x^2+3x-2006 = 0.$$
Since we seek integer solutions, the discriminant must be a perfect square:
$$(2x+1)^2 - 4(x^2+3x-2006) = -8x+8025=n^2.$$
We need $n$ to be odd, so we write $n=2k+1$ and rearrange to get
$$x = \frac{1}{8}(8024-4k-4k^2) = \frac{1}{2}(2006-k-k^2)$$
and thus
$$y = \frac{-(2x+1)\pm n}{2} = k-x\text{ or }-x-k-1.$$
Substituting in our expression for $x$, we have
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{2}(2006-k-k^2),\frac{1}{2}(-2006+3k+k^2)\right)\text{ or }\left(\frac{1}{2}(2006k-k^2),\frac{1}{2}(-2008-k+k^2)\right),\qquad k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: I suspect that if you substitute $-1-k$ for $k$ in the first solution you'll get the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that
$$2006=(x+y)^2+3x+y.\tag{1}$$
Then also
$$8024=4(x+y)^2+12x+4y=4x^2+8xy+4y^2+12x+4y=(2x+2y+1)^2+2x-1,$$
or equivalently
$$(2x+2y+1)^2=8025-2x.$$
We see that $8025-2x$ must be an odd perfect square.
Conversely, for any odd perfect square $z^2$ the pair
$$x=\frac{8025-z^2}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
y=\frac{z-2x-1}{2}=\frac{z^2+z-8026}{2},$$
are two integers that satisfy $(1)$.